# Where to store authenticated user profile in react/redux application

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to Redux and building a React/Redux application. A user will login to the application
and when the user is authenticated, I plan on returning a user profile which will consist of
1. User Lastname
2. User Firstname
3. User EmailAddress
4. User group.

As the users begin to navigate from page to page I will be using the usergroup they belong
to hide/show some sections on different components/pages.

Where can I store this userprofile information which should be accessible from any of 
my components if needed. Links to some code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can create reducer with initalState

```
 const initialState = {
     firstname: '',
     lastname: '',
     email: '',
     ...
 }
```

after we want to create dispatcher function which fetches data from server and dispatches it to store.

```
export const funnyDispatch = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch('http://example.com/api');
    dispatch({
       type: 'FUNNY_DATA',
       payload: response.userData
    })
}
```

then declare reducer function which describes how state changes.

```
function FunnyReducer(state=initalState, action){
     switch(action.type){
         case 'FUNNY_ACTION': 
             return {
                ...state,
                firstname: action.payload.firstname, //firstname is property from data which is fetched from server (userData)
                lastname: action.payload.lastname,
                email: action.payload.email
             }
         default: return state
     }
}
```

and we got our data in store.

check [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/) for more details

**EDIT**

and when you need to get data from store you can use react-redux's connect method.

you declare variable called mapStateToProps (you can choose any name) which takes state as argument (we can't call it store because it is not store instance, it is state value) and returns desired properties from initial state (declared in your reducer)

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    firstname: state.yourReducerName.firstname,
    lastname: state.yourReducerName.lastname
})
// yourReducerName is name you give your reducer when you config your store with createStore or combineReducers
```

then what you do is simple export

```
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
     yourDispatchFunction: (dispatch) => {} //you can export funnyDispatch in this component and put it here
 })(YourComponent);
```

and you get state properties with

```
this.props.lastname
```

and you can dispatch function in your event handler (or lifecycle method) like so:

```
this.props.nameYouGaveToFunnyDispatch()
```

Comment: At what point will the above happen?  I am used to creating an action which makes a call to the webservice, returns the necessary data and then create an entry in the rootreducer, then call the actual reducer.

Comment: The question is how do I get this object in other components?

Comment: see edited answer and first read redux docs. it will help you understand concept

Answer (score -2):

Storing the user information in the redux store is very common. You should then use `mapStateToProps` on any component that needs to access `state.users`